# Php string If contain echo that string

Tags: php, string

My Php mysql out put is array i need if string contain particular character i need print that string only

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) { 
 echo $row2['link'];
} 

Output is:
http://www.videoweed.es/file/b38300afda3e6
http://www.novamov.com/video/303a4428f6c6a
http://www.movshare.net/video/081aaa1356a6b
```

i need like this

```
 if (strpos($a,'videoweed') !== false) {
 echo $row2['link'];
  }
```

it show out put is:

```
 http://www.videoweed.es/file/b38300afda3e6
http://www.novamov.com/video/303a4428f6c6a
http://www.movshare.net/video/081aaa1356a6b
```

I need output only;

```
 http://www.videoweed.es/file/b38300afda3e6
```

Comment: And your problem/question is..?

Comment: You have all the pieces. Try putting it together.

Comment: so add in the extra text... it's not like you can only have one echo call in a script.

Comment: your question is not clear please elaborate a little bit, what i understand is you have to assign $row2['link'] to a variable  instead of echo $row2['link'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answer in your code. Just need to assemble it. check this:-

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) { 
  if (strpos($row2['link'],'videoweed') !== false) {

  echo $row2['link'];
  }

}
```

Comment: I would like to note it probably is simpler to use SQL to get only the results you need instead of parsing in PHP. That said, this is the PHP-specific solution.

Comment: Lool simple mistake... sorry it wast my 3 hours time, work now

Comment: If it works for you , then mark as an answer for others help. thanks.